# how do I make device specific selectors in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am wondering how to (and if you can) write device specific selectors.

I have done a google search for it and didn't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you could use some code to add a class to the body of the page with the device name/type etc.. and use that to target elements.

Comment: It would be more useful to have all the CSS rules you need for any device and then use javascript to choose the ones you want to have (applying relevant classes onto HTML elements) for that particular device. Devices will change and hardcoding certain devices or device signatures is not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors match elements based on information within the document tree. The device has nothing to do with selector matching whatsoever. So it doesn't make sense to be able to write device-specific selectors.

You were probably looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) — that's the module that deals with device-specific CSS.